# Flutter Failed to build - Gradle error. How do I resolved this

Tags: flutter, build-error

`Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 2 XL in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile').

  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' method 'useAndroidX()' should not be annotated with: @Input.

    Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Remove the annotations.
    2. Rename the method.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_method for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' property 'ndkConfig' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
`

flutter clean
flutter doctor -v
flutter upgrade --force
flutter packages pub cache clean

Comment: Problem:   unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurper
 @ line 8, column 8.         // This file is included from `<app>/android/settings.gradle`,
// so it can be versioned with the Flutter SDK.

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile